# ClickMarker is not working in XY Amcharts

Tags: javascript, graph, legend, amcharts

I have a requirement where I need to use customlegends in XY Amcharts.

I have implemented them, but When I have added event listeners to those legends, the function wasnt triggered. I dont know the reason, can anyone correct me what I have made a mistake.

You can check the following link for the output:

```
jsfiddle.net/u371jyjs/3/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`clickMarker`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#clickMarker) is a legend-specific event, not a top-level chart event. Put the listener for it inside the legend object:

```
legend: {
  // ...
  listeners: [{
    "event": "clickMarker",
    "method": function(event) {
      // toggle the marker state
      event.dataItem.hidden = !event.dataItem.hidden; 
      event.chart.validateNow();
    }
  }]
}
```

Demo:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "xy",
  "path": "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "y": 10,
    "x": 2,
    "value": 59,
    "y2": 5,
    "x2": 3,
    "value2": 44,
    "label": "Hello",
    "category": "0",
    "column-1": 32
  }, {
    "y": 5,
    "x": 8,
    "value": 50,
    "y2": 15,
    "x2": 8,
    "value2": 12,
    "label": "Hi",
    "category": "1000",
    "column-1": 14
  }, {
    "y": 10,
    "x": 8,
    "value": 19,
    "y2": 4,
    "x2": 6,
    "value2": 35,
    "label": "Yo"
  }, {
    "y": 6,
    "x": 5,
    "value": 65,
    "y2": 5,
    "x2": 6,
    "value2": 168,
    "label": "Howdy"
  }, {
    "y": 15,
    "x": 4,
    "value": 92,
    "y2": 13,
    "x2": 8,
    "value2": 102,
    "label": "Hi there"
  }, {
    "y": 13,
    "x": 1,
    "value": 8,
    "y2": 2,
    "x2": 0,
    "value2": 41,
    "label": "Morning"
  }, {
    "y": 1,
    "x": 6,
    "value": 35,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2": 3,
    "value2": 16,
    "label": "Afternoon"
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "position": "bottom",
    "axisAlpha": 0,

    "integersOnly": true,
    //"labelRotation": 45,
    "labelFunction": function(value) {

      // define categories
      var cats = [
        "Nick",
        "Sarah",
        "Kevin",
        "Dominick",
        "Christy",
        "Kate",
        "Julian",
        "Anita",
        "Mike",
        "Kyle",
        "Tyrese"
      ];
      return cats[value];
    }
  }, {
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left"
  }],
  "startDuration": 1.5,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[label]]",
    "bullet": "circle",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.2,
    "bulletAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "valueField": "value",
    "xField": "x",
    "yField": "y",
    "maxBulletSize": 100
  }, {
    "balloonText": "[[label]]",
    "bullet": "diamond",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.2,
    "bulletAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "valueField": "value2",
    "xField": "x2",
    "yField": "y2",
    "maxBulletSize": 100
  }],
  "legend": {
    "switchable": true,
    "textClickEnabled": true,
    "data": [{
      title: "One",
      color: "#3366CC",
      hidden: true
    }, {
      title: "Two",
      color: "#FFCC33"
    }],
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "clickMarker",
      "method": function(event) {
        event.dataItem.hidden = !event.dataItem.hidden;
        event.chart.validateNow()
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/xy.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<div id="clicked">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you help me on the other question which I posted, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323661/display-balloon-in-amcharts-on-click

Comment: I have a quick question, how can I hide the data when I click on One and Two legends

Comment: For your second question - data elements aren't tied to custom legend markers. Is there a reason why you're using custom legend markers instead of the built-in markers? You don't need to write custom code to make the built-in markers work, and it doesn't look like you're doing anything that necessitates the need for the data array over the built-in ones.

Comment: If you wanted to hide/remove elements on a custom marker on click, you can adapt the code in [this knowledge base article](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/generate-legend-markers-column/) for your needs. It's for a serial chart, but the concept is the same for an XY chart, though it's likely easier to just use the built-in markers instead and adapt your config accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I need to show someother data which is not label.As a reason, I need custom legends.

Comment: Well, your only option is to use the concepts in the article/demo I linked to hide specific points, as you need to remove points from the dataProvider to accomplish it. If you want to hide the entire graph through a custom marker, you can access the chart variable through the event and call show/hide graph (or toggle `hidden` on the graph object) based on the marker selected. How you determine which graph to hide from the selected marker is up to you.